# What is the Ethereum network architecture? What are the major components of this?

Tags: network, architecture

I'm looking for a visual (preferred) or a description of what Ethereum "looks" like to a network architect.

For example, in contrasting Bitcoin, it consists of:

**"Full nodes"**

- runs C++ code
- Uses [QT for cross platform graphics](http://www.qt.io)
- Peers use a mesh P2P discovery engine that uses port 8333
- Uses 80GB of disk space for the blockchain

**Miners**

- ASIC hardware that calculates a hash

**SPV Wallet**

- A lightweight method for a wallet to send and receive transactions without running a "full node"

(These are incomplete skeleton entries that describe Bitcoin.  This post is about Ethereum ;)

---

So, that being said, what are the major software components of Ethereum?

How do they connect?

What are they used for?

Answer (score 2):

As of now ([Homestead release](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/index.html)) there is only one node implementation, however the may be customisations across instances. Most notably:

- mining is not enabled by default on an Ethereum node, but can be [selectively enabled](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/mining.html#cpu-mining) as a config option
- if mining is enabled, you may want to run your Ethereum node on a HW platform that is more efficient at the types of computations required for the mining computations (note that Ethereum mining computations are [ASIC resistant](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33/by-what-mechanism-are-asic-based-miners-made-less-favourable), but you will still get better odds on a platform with plenty of [GPU and RAM capacity](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/mining.html#gpu-mining)).
- if you're into mining, then you may want to add your node to a [mining pool](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/mining.html#pool-mining)

Beyond the Homestead release, there are plans for the introduction of a [light client](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/mining.html#gpu-mining).