# what does memory hard mean in ETH POW?

Tags: proof-of-work

I came across the term memory-hard while ready about ETH POW algorithm. What does it mean when someone says that POW is memory hard?

Comment: Also: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33/by-what-mechanism-are-asic-based-miners-made-less-favourable

Answer (score 0):

"Memory Hard" implies that amount of memory required to mine Ether with POW is significantly higher as compared to other implementations (such as Bitcoin).

This makes mining difficult since latency introduced by DAG lookups slows down mining.

This article explains the issue :

https://www.vijaypradeep.com/blog/2017-04-28-ethereums-memory-hardness-explained/

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum uses Dagger-Hashimoto algorithm for POW.

miners use DAG dataset refreshed for each 30,000 blocks and mining process includes  [strict memory hard hashing functions](http://www.hashcash.org/papers/memohash.pdf)

because of memory hard hashing functions, GPU and hardware specialized in Bitcoin mining are not faster than general CPU.

Comment: GPUs _are_ faster than CPUs when mining ETH. However, ASICs (i.e. specialised hardware) offer no advantage.

Comment: In Bitcoin, GPU have higher hashrate than CPU  .   
However, there is no big difference between CPU and GPU mining in Ethereum, isn't it?